# How can i make a Gps Location provider? (USB gps)

Tags: android, service, gps, provider

I have a android device without GPS, but i want to run apps that need GPS.

For example i want to make an app like these to use bluetooth gps but instead of using BT im using Android Open Accesory to make an USB GPS, so my problem is not how to comunicate the GPS to Android, my problem is how to make a service/provider that is recognised by android an the rest of the apps could use.

it could be made?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible, but maybe not worth:

write a driver to your usb gps and map it at android os level. JNI level and core OS.
use it in your app.

probably it worth to buy a new phone with GPS instead.